# move files name in excel to a specific folder

Tags: excel, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file that reads from excel file. then move them to a specique folder.

lets say in the excel , there are:

```
111.txt
222.txt
333.txt
512.txt
```

I want a batch file that move files into a specific directory that have the above names.

how can I achieve that ?
(I am using xp , and I the directory is D:)

Comment: I would suggest using powershell rather than a batch file, but it might depend on what version of XP and Excel you have. Do you have XP SP3? If so, what version of Excel?

Comment: Is it an option to convert the excel file to csv?

Comment: @DeanOC I want to use it on sevrel pcs, some of them uses xp , others on windows 7 the same goes for excel , different version of excel

Comment: @Stephan well its not a problem , we can conert it

Comment: How does the list look like? Is this the only column?

Comment: @Stephan how to specify the destination ?

Comment: @Stephan another problem occured , the destination that I get the files are in the shared , is there a way that I can access the shared drive and get the scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /d "d:\files"
for /f %%i in ("C:\where the file resides\file.csv") do (
  echo move "%%i" "D:\New\"
)
```

remove the `echo` if output seems ok

Comment: the files are under D:/files .. and I want to move them to D:/New , How to do that , with the above command??

Comment: oh thats helpulf stpehan THANK You, however can you explain whatdoes /f , in , do and %%i mean ?

Comment: `/f` is - kind of - "filemode"; `in` and `do` are part of the `for`-syntax; `%%i` is like a `for`-internal variable. See `for /?` for more explanation. `for` is one of the mightiest commands in batch, it's worth the time to learn about it.

Comment: another problem occured , the destination that I get the files are in the shared , is there a way that I can access the shared drive and get the scripts ?